# How to add data into a new DataFrame based on values in a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, if-statement, append

For example:

```
[{'day': 'monday', 'sunny': 'yes', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'yes'}, 
 {'day': 'tuesday', 'sunny': 'no', 'windy': 'yes', 'ended': 'no'}]
```

The values (the name of the day, and the answers i.e. yes, no, etc.) are taken from user input (user can enter **as many as they want**). I need to sort these into a DataFrame where values are organized, for example:

- If it's both sunny and windy, the values must be sorted under the heading GOOD WEATHER.
- If it's just sunny and not windy, it must be under HOT WEATHER, etc....
- If the day has ended, nothing for that day should be shown.

After I sort the DataFrame this way, I have to write it to a csv file. I'm using pandas.
So if e.g. I need to iterate using list comprehension, please explain to me how to do so.

I'm new to Python, so please use simpler explanations/functions etc.

Edit: I was referring to the yes and no values eg. if sunny == yes and windy == yes then it needs to be sorted under GOOD WEATHER.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Also it is unclear about the `values` to sort you're talking, because each line has it's windy, sunny, values

Comment: I was referring to the yes and no values eg. if sunny == yes and windy == yes then it needs to be sorted under GOOD WEATHER.